# Why does the resource hacker editor show up instead of log on screen

Tags: logging, resources

I pressed the power button until the computer shutdown. When I pressed the power on button, it booted and then instead of the login prompt, a resource hacker editor appeared. I tried closing it but it kept coming back. I restarted the computer again and again and the same thing kept happening. I even tried restarting in safe mode and last known good condition but nothing worked. What should I do?

Computer: Acer Aspire One
processor speed: 1.6 Ghz
OS: Windows XP sp3

Comment: That's one for the books!

Comment: For the record, I completely disabled any internet connection on the computer about two months ago so I'm sure someone wasn't hacking me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I forgot to mention that I was using Logonloader. Logonloader is a program that allows you to change the logonscreen on your computer to something else. But be careful

The problem was that I had the wrong logonui.exe program in the wrong folder.
ResHack.exe was in the Windows Vista Logonscreen file folder which was in the logonscreens file folder. The logonscreens folder is where logonloader gets different logonscreens to execute. So Logonloader executes any files ending in ".exe" located in the logonscreens folder.

Last week, I opened up Logonloader and checked the option to randomize the log on screens without realizing that ResHack was in one of the Logonscreen files namely Windows Vista Logonscreen. Logon loader just looked for any file with a ".exe" extension in the Windows Vista Logonscreen folder and executed that.

So each time I restarted the computer, Logonloader would execute ResHacker because it thought ResHacker was a logonscreen within the Windows Vista folder.

The solution: I located a real Logonscreen.exe file in the logonscreens folder and used the already open ResHacker editor to switch the name of that Logonscreen.exe file to ResHack.exe and then change the actual name of ResHack.exe to something else. If logonloader was to execute ResHack again, then I would be able to log in.

It worked.

Answer (score 2):

Do a Windows Repair installation.  If you have the original Windows CD/DVD you can re-run the installation and force a repair, which will replace all system files with the Windows default files.

Comment: My computer doesn't have a CD drive.

Comment: Does it have a [usb](http://superuser.com/questions/227945/is-is-possible-to-install-windows-xp-in-usb-drive)